# How to push notification of battery status level on IONIC framework?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2

Is there a way to push notification of battery status level on Ionic mobile application even if the app is close?

A background process to monitor the level of battery. When it reaches critical level will push a notification.

I am using ionic 2.

Comment: For running in background check this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-run-app-forever-in-background-like-whatsapp/12546, for push notifications and for notifications here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/